# LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Board_Game, expected /Users/username/personal_projects/board_game_app/app/models/board_game.rb to define it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The error is as you see it in the title when I try to run bundle exec rake db:seed.

My seed file:

```
  #1
 Board_Game.create(
    title: "5 Second Rule",
    base_game: "",
    min_players: 3,
    max_players: "",
    time_needed: 20,
    company: "Patch",
  )
  #2
  Board_Game.create(
    title: "7 Wonders",
    base_game: "",
    min_players: 2,
    max_players: 7,
    time_needed: 30,
    company: "Repos Production",
  )
  #3
  Board_Game.create(
    title: "7 Wonders Babel",
    base_game: 2,
    min_players: 2,
    max_players: 7,
    time_needed: 40,
    company: "Repos Production",
  )
  #4
  Board_Game.create(
    title: "Alhambra", 
    base_game: "",
    min_players: 2,
    max_players: 6,
    time_needed: 45,
    company: "Queen Games",
  )
  #5
  Board_Game.create(
    title: "Agricola",
    base_game: "",
    min_players: 1,
    max_players: 5,
    time_needed: 30, 
    company: "Z-Man Games",
  )
  #6
  Board_Game.create(
    title: "Agricola: Farmers of the Moor",
    base_game: 5,
    min_players: 1,
    max_players: 5,
    time_needed: 30,
    company: "Z-Man Games",
  )
  #7
  Board_Game.create(
    title: "Arkham Horror",
    base_game: "",
    min_players: 1,
    max_players: 8,
    time_needed: 120,
    company: "Fantasy Flight Games", 
  )
  #8
  Board_Game.create(
    title: "Ascending Empires",
    base_game: "",
    min_players: 2, 
    max_players: 4,
    time_needed: 75,
    company: "Z-Man Games",
  )
  #9
  Board_Game.create(
    title: "Ascension: Chronicle of the Godslayer",
    base_game: "",
    min_players: 2,
    max_players: 4,
    time_needed: 30,
    company: "Gary Games",
  )
  #10
  Board_Game.create(
    title: "Ascension: Storm of Souls",
    base_game: "",
    min_players: 1,
    max_players: 4,
    time_needed: 30,
    company: "Gary Games",
  )
  #11
  Board_Game.create(
    title: "Bootleggers",
    base_game: "",
    min_players: 3,
    max_players: 6,
    time_needed: 90,
    company: "Mayday Games",
  )
  #12
  Board_Game.create(
    title: "Carcassonne",
    base_game: "",
    min_players: 2,
    max_players: 5,
    time_needed: 35,
    company: "Z-Man Games",
  )
  #13
  Board_Game.create(
    title: "Cash 'n Guns",
    base_game: "",
    min_players: 4,
    max_players: 8,
    time_needed: 30,
    company: "Repos Production",
  )
  #14
  Board_Game.create(
    title: "Camel Cup",
    base_game: "",
    min_players: 2,
    max_players: 8,
    time_needed: 20,
    company: "Pegasus Spiele",
  )
  #15
  Board_Game.create(
    title: "Castles of Mad King Ludwig",
    base_game: "",
    min_players: 1,
    max_players: 4,
    time_needed: 90, 
    company: "Bézier Games",
  )
  #16
  Board_Game.create(
    title: "Caverna: the Cave Farmers",
    base_game: "",
    min_players: 1,
    max_players: 7,
    time_needed: 30,
    company: "MayFair Games", 
  )
  #17
  Board_Game.create(
    title: "Codenames",
    base_game: "",
    min_players: 2,
    max_players: 8,
    time_needed: 15,
    company: "Czech Games Edition", 
  )
  #18
  Board_Game.create(
    title: "Dead of Winter", 
    base_game: "",
    min_players: 2,
    max_players: 5,
    time_needed: 60,
    company: "Plaid Hat Games",
  )
  #19
  Board_Game.create(
    title: "Mistborn: House War",
    base_game: "",
    min_players: 3,
    max_players: 5,
    time_needed: 60,
    company: "Crafty", 
  )
  #20
  Board_Game.create(
    title: "Nefertiti",
    base_game: "",
    min_players: 3,
    max_players: 4,
    time_needed: 45, 
    company: "Rio Grande Games",
  )
  puts "database seeded"
```

My board_game.rb:

```
class BoardGame < ApplicationRecord

end
```

I'm just trying to seed some board games before I try building a user with a library of board games and such, but I'm not sure what is going wrong with the model. I haven't programmed in about a month now and only went through a web development boot camp before that, so I'm a noob. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is called `BoardGame` so you should be using `BoardGame.create` in the seed file

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you! This fixed it.